# Return list of entities from web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, entity-framework, edmx

I use an Entity Framework (edmx file) for my model, and I'm using WCF to access my model.
When  try to return list of an entity data model (example table object), i get an error:

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error.

Here is my WCF code. IService.cs:

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(IPesananCallBack), SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
public interface IPelayanWebService
{
   [OperationContract]
   List<table> GetAllTables();
}
```

Service.cs:

```
public List<table> GetAllTables()
{
    TableModel model = new TableModel();
    return model.GetAllTables();
}
```

My code in model:

```
public List<table> GetAllTables()
{
    using (restoicdbEntities ent = new restoicdbEntities())
    {
        return ent.table.ToList();
    }
}
```

in my client, I just call that function, and the error occured.
Do I have to create my own data contract? Is there anyway to generate the datacontract from the edmx?

**Update:**
This is the generated code from Entity Framework:

```
[EdmEntityTypeAttribute(NamespaceName="restoicdbModel", Name="table")]
[Serializable]
[DataContractAttribute(IsReference=true)]
public partial class table: EntityObject
{
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 ID_TABLE
    {
        get
        {
            return _ID_TABLE;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ID_TABLE != value)
            {
                OnID_TABLEChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("ID_TABLE");
                ID_TABLE = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("ID_TABLE");
                OnID_TABLEChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 ID_TABLE;
    partial void OnID_TABLEChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnID_TABLEChanged();
}
```

Comment: What version of the Entity Framework are you using? Are your entities POCOs?

Comment: Im using version 2.0, my entity is generated from edmx.

Comment: EF 2.0? After 1.0 [it was 4.0 then 4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 5.0 and now 6.0alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework#History)

Comment: actually how do i look the version? i looked it from the xml..
<edmx:Edmx Version="2.0"

Comment: Do your entities derive from [EntityObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.dataclasses.entityobject.aspx)?

Comment: @Steve yes it derives from EntityObject

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121877/wcf-entity-framework-data-contracts

Comment: so i can't use the generated code from entity framework for WCF? i have to create my own class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the link provided by Steve Wilkes, [WCF, Entity Framework & Data Contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1121877/wcf-entity-framework-data-contracts), it looks like it is not good to pass entity object from web service. So I have to create my own Data Transfer Object which is a mapping from the entity object, then pass it from the web service.