# Converting entity framework model to data contract

Tags: c#, wcf, frameworks, entity

I have created a wcf web service that enable user access to database. For database model I use entity framework. Problem is that I have so much  classes inside of entity framework and it will take too much time to write a datacontract by hand. Is there a easy way to avoid that?

Comment: similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1122289/1099260

Comment: Thanks, I ve seen that solution but.. I hoped thatin Visual Studio 2012 there are some features that would help me to do it :/ Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cant believe it. Entity framework classes dont need to be taged as [DataContract]. I got error when consuming service with wcf test client, but my wpf client is working great. I am so sorry about that.