# Load Child Entities with EntityFramework in WCF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf

The following code is a WCF project.
I am loading child data of a table with EntityFramekwork (v.6).
The code as it follows.

This is the code in the repository.

```
public IEnumerable<Messages> GetMessagesList()
{
    return context.Messages.Include(e=>e.Users).Include(e=>e.Codes).ToList();
}
```

This is the code in the service:

```
public IEnumerable<Messages> GetMessagesList()
{
   var res =  messagesRepository.GetMessagesList();
   return res;
}
```

With or without the include method it returns data when debugging.

But the problem is that when I add the include method to load the related child entities in my client. When I load only the Messages Entity it is alright.

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:2341/DataService.svc. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.

Inner exception message:

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on
>   a receive.

When testing with the WCF TEST CLIENT:

[image]

Where is the problem actually here how to pass the Messages entity with the children loaded to the client without getting the errors. The errors are quite generic can`t understand the actual problem.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to return Entity objects from service. It is not possible because Entity objects can not be Serializable by default. So you can not return from service directly. You can map your Entity to DTO than return it. Check [wcf-entity-framework-data-contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122289/5519709)

Answer (score 0):

I added  **[DataContract(IsReference = true)]** to the model Classes and all of the related data from the child tables wereloaded with eager loading. This was the solution in this case.